# How to populate data on bootstrap nav-tabs in while loop using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have `nav-tabs` inside the `list-group` and all of them inside `while loop`, I managed to fetch data from `mysql` to `nav-tabs`. the problem is that contents appear on first `nav-tabs` only and when I shift to the next line of tabs redirects me to first line of tabs instead of showing its own data as I have looped it inside `while loop` in order to show all independent contents on each line. I have two lines of `nav-tabs`.

My `php bootstrap` code:

```
                <!-- Start List Group -->
           <ul  class="list-group  p-1 col-lg-12 ">

       <?php while($mysql_result = mysql_fetch_array($myslQuery)){ ?>

   <li name="applicant"  class="list-group-item">

 <!-- Left side of profile -->
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <center>
    <span class="text-left">
    <img src="<?php echo "../".$mysql_result['passport_photofile'];?>" class=" img-lg  rounded-circle">        
  </span></center>

        <div class="table-responsive panel">
         <table class="table">
             <tbody>
             <!-- Decision buttons    -->
                 <tr>
                <td class="text-center">

             <button class="btn btn-success text-white btn-block"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Admit</button>       

              <button class="btn btn-dark text-white btn-block"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Reject</button>

                </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                   </div>        
                    </div>
                    <!-- end -->

  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">

       <!-- Nav Tabs headers -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PersonalInf" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Personal info</a></li>

          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#DegreeAndC" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Degree & certificate</a></li>

      </ul>
      <!-- end -->

        <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- Presonal info -->
         <div id="PersonalInf" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="table-responsive panel">
                 <div class="item">

          <ul class="">
           <li>Fist name: <?php echo  $mysql_result['firstname']; ?>  
           </li> 
           <li>Last name: <?php echo  $mysql_result['lastname']; ?>
           </li>
           <li>Gender: <?php echo  $mysql_result['gender']; ?>
           </li>  

          </ul>
          </div>           
             </div>
              </div>
                <!-- end -->


  <!-- Degree and certificate -->
            <div id="DegreeAndC" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="table-responsive panel">

          <div class="item">      
          <ul class="">
           <li>Program: <?php echo  $mysql_result['program']; ?>  
           </li> 
          <li>Academic year: <?php echo  $mysql_result['academic_year']; ?>
           </li>
          </ul>
      </div> 
      </div>
       </div>
      <!-- End -->

                 </div>
              <!-- Tab content -->

            </div>
               </li>
                <?php } ?>

                      </ul>
```

Comment: You are duplicating ids so it's focusing the first found. However a working example with the generated html and javascript would be helpful.

Comment: @msg, Thanks I understand , please  can you help me with the link ?

Comment: Just use a counter or the record id to make it unique `div id="DegreeAndC-<?= $i++ ?>"`

Comment: @msg, wow nice idea sir, let me try , but if it doesn't complicate you you can try to show me at least on one line on my showed example above

Comment: @msg, I tried your way, but now for active tab it's ok but for other tabs , the contents come as the results of active tab (the first one).  the way I made it to rename `href value and id`  : 



              `<?php 
 $count =0 ;
           while($mysql_result = mysql_fetch_array($myslQuery)){ 
             $ids = $count ++;

            ?>

            href="<?php echo "#PersonalInf".$ids; ?>"

            id="<?php echo "#PersonalInf".$ids; ?>" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using duplicated ids so when you click on a link it's focusing the first found. You can use a counter or the record id to make them unique.

```
$i = 0;

while($mysql_result = mysql_fetch_array($myslQuery)) {
?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PersonalInf-<?= $i ?>" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Personal info</a></li>
<!-- Rest of your code -->
<div id="PersonalInf-<?= $i ?>" class="tab-pane fade">
<?php
    $i++;
}
```

However, I don't think you need anchors at all, since in order to be able to click the pane you must have it in the viewport.

Comment: ,Thanks for great courage, As I mentioned it in above comment, I did it in the same way of you , but the problem now each tab I access , shows the same results(default results)  of active tab(first tab of row)

Comment: @AlexisMUGWANEZA That looks like a javascript problem. Have you initialized the bootstrap tabs ?

Comment: I just have all libraries of JavaScript, is there any specific library for bootstrap tabs ?

Comment: @AlexisMUGWANEZA Take a look at the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior). Make sure it's the same version that you are using. Or add a sample of your generated html to your question if you are still having problems.

Comment: Be bless tonight, your solution works very fine, It's my mistake on ids I was putting `#` too, instead of  `id=id="<?php echo "PersonalInf".$ids; ?>"` I wrote `id="<?php echo "#PersonalInf".$ids; ?>"`

Comment: And if I have 400 millions of loops what ids there would be?

Comment: @EvgenySudakov 400M loops or 400M results? Either way, you should probably look into pagination, category browsing or other kind of solution.